# Auto-unmount USB drive

Tags: 13.04, usb, udev, unmount

I used to work for a long time with ubuntu 10.10 and I changed to a recent machine so I had to move to Ubuntu 13.04. One feature I'm now missing is the auto umount of usb drives.
I've not been able to find easy info on internet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu pubpub! It's great that you are posting this, although you put in the question/answer form. So you should [edit] your post to only make it a "question", and then answer your own question =).

Comment: Since there is no question, shouldn't this be on a personal blog?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have no blog and I found askubuntu so usefull when you have a question that I prefered to post data on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

[pubpub](https://askubuntu.com/users/182994/pubpub) solution (after I [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/330992/revisions) his question):

> Creating `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-usb-autounmount.rules`:
>
> ```
> # Auto-unmount USB storage (on remove):
> ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sd??", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger  auto umounting  %k"
> ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sd??", RUN+="/bin/umount /dev/%k"
> ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sd??", RUN+="/bin/umount -lf /dev/%k"
> ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sd???", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger  auto umounting  %k"
> ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sd???", RUN+="/bin/umount /dev/%k"
> ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVNAME}=="/dev/sd???", RUN+="/bin/umount -lf /dev/%k"*
> ```
>
> Of course you still have to be carefull about opened files mainly in
>   writing.
>
> Hope it will help others.