# Does Ubuntu 14.04 LTS support safe remove USB

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I'm new to Ubuntu. I know that windows has a feature that allows you to remove your USB flash drive without having to go to the drive, right click and choosing safely remove.
This prevents you from corrupting your files if you quickly unplug your flash.

What I want to know is. Does Ubuntu have a similar feature? can I just unplug my USB devices and my files wont get corrupted or must I always go to the drive right click and chose safely remove?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  What Windows calls a "safe remove" is called an "unsafe remove" in any other OS. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it does. There are [mount options `sync` and `dirsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/mount.8.html) for file systems which disable all or some file system caches respectively and *should* achieve what you have in mind, but I wouldn't bet any important data on the robustness of that “feature” in any OS. It also degrades performance and the life time of flash memory cells.

Comment: @DavidFoerster. look at the answer from the OP below.  So I respectfully disagree with you on this, as I gave the OP what he was asking for.  *Now* we can warn him about the disadvantages. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way of doing this, but if you're asking the question, you're *probably* not going to like the answer: [Auto-unmount USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330992/auto-unmount-usb-drive)

Comment: **And now we come to the part why you're not going to like this**: The Microsoft way is the convenient way, *but*
you will wear out your USB drive more quickly as the individual cells have a limited amount of writes.  Having a cache is actually better, because the life of your USB drive will be larger. Your choice though!  >:-) I'm just pointing out that it *is* possible.

Comment: Thank You. I accepted your answer but it doesn't let me vote it up. I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

yes it does.

just right click on USB icon in launcher and click `safely remove` or `eject`

[image: ubuntu launcher usb icon]

Comment: Or pull it into the trash. This will also eject the drive, like on Mac OS X.

Comment: @the_Seppi for real or you are kidding me

Comment: Go on, try it. In 13.04 it worked. I'm not using Unity any more, but I doubt the removed it.

Comment: Sorry Edward, that's not what William is asking...  What he's asking is: "Can I just yank it out *without* unmounting, ejecting or doing anything at all???" which is possible, but much more difficult... ;-)